# How to avoid tilde ~ in Bash prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

I would like to remove the tilde from displaying within the PS1 variable.

My current PS1 string:

```
PS1="\h:\w\n$"
```

And the prompt looks like this:

```
lnx-hladky:/tmp/plugtmp
$
```

I don't like that the $HOME directory is displayed as tilde. Can this be avoided?

It causes problems, example:

```
lnx-hladky:~/DOC
$
```

Documentation says:

```
\w : the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde 
\W: the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
```

Is there any possibility to avoid $HOME being abbreviated with a tilde?

I have found one way around but I feel like it's overcomplicated:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\e[4;35m$(date +%T)\e[24m$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)\e[m\n"'
PS1=$
```

Can anyone propose a better solution? I have a feeling it's not quite OK to run so many commands just to get prompt. (date,whoami,hostname,pwd).

Comment: what "problems" does the tilde cause in the example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

bash runs expansions in the prompt; just make sure to escape them.

```
PS1='\h:$(pwd)\n$'
```

Comment: That answers my question. I didn't know there is such possibility. Thanks a lot, Ignacio!

Comment: @Jirka: You can also use: `PS1='\h:$PWD\n$'.

Comment: Jirka's solution executes `pwd` on every prompt. Dennis' solution does not, just fetches environment variable PWD, which is much cheaper.

Comment: `pwd` is a bash builtin. The assertion that `${PWD}` is "much cheaper" than `$(pwd)` is without evidence.

Comment: For some reasons with `$(pwd)` my prompt is not getting updated on `cd` (so stuck in `/home/username`). Any ideas?

Comment: @anxieux: you have to quote with single quotes, not double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run as many commands as you showed in your example. `bash` provides shortcuts for most of the things you mentioned.

Your example:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\e[4;35m$(date +%T)\e[24m$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)\e[m\n"'
PS1=$
```

can be rewritten as :

```
PS1='\e[4;35m\t\e[24m\u@\h:\w\e[m\n'
```

Where `\t` shows the time (in 24 hour format), `\u` shows the current username, '\h' shows the hostname -- the `bash` man page discusses [these and the rest of the escapes available](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt) for your prompt.

Even if you expand the `~` to the full path, if you don't know which user is running the command and you're switching users regularly, you can create problems with file permissions or executable permissions.

Comment: Hi, my intention was to replace \w with the full path including FULL $HOME path. Thanks to Ignacio I'm now using  PS1='\e[4;35m\t\e[24m\u@\h:$(pwd)\e[m\n$' which has solved my problem:-)

Comment: Perfect -- I like including `\u` so that I know who I am. Don't forget to accept Ignacio's answer -- click the check box to the left of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm new to this forum. It's a great place.

Comment: \u@\h:$PWD (note the colon) can be used as input for scp

Answer (score 0):

I am using below setting in my .bash_profile file

```
$ export PS1='\e[1;34m\D{%T %d.%m.%Y} \[\033[00;39m\]\u\[\033[00;32m\]@$IP:\[\033[00;33m\]$(pwd)/\n\\$\[\033[00m\] '

21:40:08 14.12.2017 vmware@10.112.202.228:/home/vmware/Downloads/
```